# D3 Stacked Bar chart : issue calculating and displaying sum/total of each bar

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, nvd3.js

I am trying to calculate the sum/total value of each stacked bar in the chart and display it above each bar

https://jsfiddle.net/n0zjpyow/1/

Desired output:

[image]

(note:totals not accurate in image)

I am using the nest and rollup functions but the result from this is the total of each series and not each stacked bar.

```
var keys = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return (d.key) })
.rollup(function (v) {
  return d3.keys(v[0]).filter(function(p, i){return i}) //filter out the heading
    .reduce(function(s, p){   //sum each of the other members
      //p is the category being summed
      return (s[p] = d3.sum(d3.values(v[0][p][0])), s);
    }, {});
})
.map(data);
```

Output

```
{1: {values: 190000000}
 2A: {values: 152000000}
 2B: {values: 190000000}
 Non: {values: 128000000}}
```

I am getting confused with how to apply this to the data structure i have for the chart (which cannot be modified)

How can i calculate the total of the values in each bar ? Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Do all the values in the data array always have the same keys? 

i.e. is it possible that `data[1].values` has more dates than `data[0].values`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your data, a simple approach to **compute the total value** of each bar could be the following:

```
var total = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
data.forEach(e => {
  e.values.forEach( (f, i) => {
    total[i] = total[i] + f[1];
  });
});
```

where you are going through each object (`1`, `2A`, `2B`, `Non`), and then, through each date (`Jan '19 S`, `Jan '19 U`, ..., `Mar '19 U`). The result is accumulated in the array `total`:

```
[ 660000000, 1015000000, 598000000, 484000000, 528000000, 396000000 ]
```

Regarding **displaying the total** of each bar, you can find a potential solution in this  snippet:

https://jsfiddle.net/s5npfdo0/

with the following output:

[image]

Some points to take into account:

- AFAIK, NVD3 doesn't allow to show the total value of each bar in a multibar graph (e.g., see [this issue](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/736)). The solution is to implement that part yourself. In my snippet, the implementation is quite simple, but it lacks some features, for example if you resize the window the total value positions are not recalculated. If this is a problem for your use case, I can try to solve it.
- The function `addTotalValue()` need to be called *after* the graph is completely drawn, because of that is called with `setTimeout(addTotalValue, 500);`
- The yDomain computed automatically by NVD3 from data doesn't give space for the total value labels, so yDomain should be forced to another value: `.yDomain([0, 1100e6])`. Here is computed 1100e6 manually and is only suitable for this data, but is shouldn't be difficult to compute automatically from data.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write such a detailed and helpful answer, you have made my Friday !! It's working perfectly for me.

Comment: Glad to be of help!  :)

Comment: One other quick question if i may. The total for the largest value is not displaying and i guess the issue is with the yDomain value. In your fiddle i see you specify a value but what should i enter here if the total is dynamic ?

Comment: Probably, adding 10% to the largest value should be enough. I.e., yDomain=largest_value*1.1. If you need more space, try with 1.2 or 1.3